# can't find my user name in /etc/passwd nor name of my initial group in /etc/group

Tags: users, account-restrictions, nsswitch

#### Here is what i get:

```
[zehu@danville ~]$ groups
apl vboxusers
[zehu@danville ~]$ 

[zehu@danville ~]$ grep zehu /etc/passwd 
[zehu@danville ~]$ 

[zehu@danville ~]$ grep apl /etc/group
[zehu@danville ~]$ 

[zehu@danville ~]$ grep vboxusers /etc/group
vboxusers:x:1540:zehu
[zehu@danville ~]$
```

Could anyone tell me if that's normal or not? and why is that? Thanks for help!

```
 [zehu@danville ~]$ sudo grep zehu /etc/shadow  
 [zehu@danville ~]$   
 [zehu@danville ~]$ id  
 uid=1580(zehu) gid=1100(apl)     groups=1100(apl),1540(vboxusers)  
 [zehu@danville ~]$ getent group apl  
 apl:x:1100: 

[zehu@danville ~]$ ypcat passwd | grep zehu
zehu:beL3WqT.4rb5Y:1580:1100:Zeyu Hu:/home/zehu:/bin/tcsh
```

Comment: I don't think it's normal. what about `/etc/shadow`? Please report the output of `id`, `whoami`. How did you login?

Comment: Does `getent group apl` output anything?

Comment: nis (former yellow page) might be in use, do you have a + (plus sign) in /etc/passwd ? LDAP might be in use also (though I don't know how to check)

Comment: I didn't find a '+' in /etc/passwd, and I'm googling what you have mentioned as nis or LDAP :(

Comment: Nis is in use. I find a NISDOMAIN in /etc/sysconfig/network.

Comment: then try `ypcat passwd | grep zehu`

Comment: Look at `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. Your system could be set up to use any or all of: local files, NIS, or LDAP.http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-1386/6jam5ahkg/index.html

Answer (score 5):

The system that you are using uses a [directory service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_service) (examples of these are  NIS, NIS+, and LDAP) for some users and groups, including yourself and your `apl` group, rather than local entries in `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`.

This is common on systems where the users and groups are administered on a central machine. It makes it easier, from a system administration standpoint, to allow users to log in on any number of other machines (login nodes or compute cluster nodes) without having to manually update the required files on all machines whenever some user or group information changes.

The `getent` utility may be used to get information about local users and groups *and* about users and groups served from a directory service.

To see your `passwd` entry, use

```
getent passwd "$LOGNAME"
```

or

```
getent passwd "$( id -u )"
```

To see your `group` entries, use

```
getent group $( id -G )
```

Change `-G` to `-g` to only get your primary group.

For more information, see

- [The NIS article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Information_Service)
- [The NIS+ article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NIS%2B)
- [The LDAP article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol)